# Android Clean Architecture

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I've created a simple android project with Android Studio. How to create layers? I mean data, presentation, domain layers using Android studio.I'm trying to understand how to use Clean Architecture pattern in my Android apps.

**As I understand** to create a new layer I need to do this Click on Project folder -> Create new Module -> Select Java Library. Am I right?

Comment: I figure out you are trying to ask if a layer of the Clean Arch., could be a Java library or an Android module or even a single package inside the same module(app)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this sample to-do app from Google:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-clean/

There will be 3 layers: presentation, domain and data.

Presentation: View related code. There are View, Presenter and its contract.

Domain: Usecase (Interactor), business objects and control objects.

Data: Repository - local (db) and remote (server).

Comment: So! As I understand to create a new layer I need to do this Click on Project folder -> Create new Module -> Select Java Library. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think you're telling him anything he doesn't already know

Comment: Check this article https://proandroiddev.com/multiple-ways-of-defining-clean-architecture-layers-bbb70afa5d4a and this project https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase